# WP7 touch an Image with MouseLeftButtonDown

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mobile

Image don't have a click event, but it have a MouseLeftButtonDown, I don't have a device and I need to know if it's working well in the real devices, Touch the image will fire this event ?!?!?

Comment: Use the emulator to debug your code.

Comment: it's working on the Emulator cuz there is a left mouse button :D
I wana to be sure if it'll work on the device.

Comment: The device has one too, people use a finger.  You really ought to get one, you'll make bad assumptions if you have no idea how phones work.

Comment: ya I know, but I'm just trying the platforms these days WP7, android, may be some iPhone later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep it works, tested on my HTC HD7 with NoDo update :)

Answer (score 0):

the most things you'll do on a real phone would work in the emulator too. the only problem with the emulator is that you have a very precise mouse pointer and the finger of an user is mostly bigger than a mouse pointer.
so there could be a problem with the design layout, but not with the event handling.

Answer (score 0):

When designing the interface, at some point try using it at low zoom % to see how it will behave.

I saw a game demo on YouTube where the developer was clicking on surprisingly small objects. I guess he never tested it on a phone.

Comment: ahaa, alot of things needed to be considered :)